# Intellij create combobox using array from another class

Tags: java, arrays, swing, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ form designer to create a JComboBox in a class called AddAccountForm. I need to use a Java array (InputArray) coming from another class (SCMain.java) to create the JComboBox. I pass this array from Main.java into AddAccountForm through AddAccountForm's constructor. Unfortunately createUIComponents runs *before* AddAccountForm's constructor runs so I cannot access it. What is the proper way to setup a JComboBox from an array coming from outside the current class?

Erroneous code below is from AddAccountForm.java and truncated to relevant parts. It returns NPE because this.InputArray has not been loaded by the constructor yet.

```
private JComboBox comboTest;
private String[] InputArray;

AddAccountForm(SCMain main, Set<String> InputSet) {
this.InputArray = InputSet.toArray(new String[InputSet.size()]);
}

private void createUIComponents() {
// TODO: place custom component creation code here
comboTest = new JComboBox(this.InputArray);
}
```

Comment: Well assuming that `createUIComponents` has been executed before your `AddAccountForm`'s constructor (???), then you should have an instance of `comboTest` within the `AddAccountForm` constructor you can work with

Comment: For some reason setting the comboTest to the InputArray within the constructor does not work; it ends up being whatever is in the model/createUIComponents before the constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the proper way to setup a JComboBox from an array coming from outside the current class?

Perhaps best is to create a ComboBoxModel object, and pass it into the class that holds the JComboBox, letting it set the combo box's model with it. You could use a [`DefaultComboBoxModel<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html) object for this for simplicity, and if you wish, simply pass the array into its constructor.

e.g.,

```
// note that method and variable names should start with lower-case letters
addAccountForm(SCMain main, Set<String> inputSet) {
    String[] inputArray = inputSet.toArray(new String[0]);
    DefaultComboBoxModel<String> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(inputArray);
    comboTest.setModel(model);
}
```

Comment: Incredible! Perfect answer, thanks. I just set the with "comboTest = new JComboBox()" in createUIComponents() and used your above code in the constructor and it worked.